# AVR Assembly: How to continue from branch instruction?

Tags: assembly, avr

say you have a branch instruction that takes you to some other subroutine, is it possible to then return to the calling subroutine  and continue?.. Something like this:

```
prog:
cp r16,r17
breq true
...

true:
out PORTA,r16
HOW DO I RETURN TO EXECUTE THE REST OF prog?
```

I hope that this illustrates the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either branch back with an unconditional branch (`rjmp`), or convert your bit of code at `true` to a subroutine and convert your `breq` to a `brne` to jump over the `rcall true` that you place after it.

```
prog:
    cp r16,r17
    brne false
    rcall true
false:
    ...

 ...

true:
    out PORTA,r16
    ret
```

Comment: Ok, what if I had multiple conditions, say 'true: false: maybe:' how could I jump back to the calling routine? Thanks for your help!

Comment: ...What I mean is, let's say that it branched to false because it met the condition, how would you get back from there?

Comment: Ok I see, I guess that way you can't go back and attempt to branch again for the other conditions if you've already branched... If that makes sense.

Comment: Branch instructions don't change any flags; simply execute another branch instruction.

Answer (score 0):

```
prog:
    cpse r16,r17
    rjmp continue
    out PORTA,r16
continue:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prog:
 cp r16,r17
 breq true  ;branch if equal
 brne false ;branch in not equal
 Rest of the program
 .
 .
 .
rjmp prog

false:
 Do something
 .
 .
ret

true:
 out PORTA,r16
 ;HOW DO I RETURN TO EXECUTE THE REST OF prog?
 ;Add a return statement, that will continue where you left
ret
```